# Get sum of the values from form fields with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamic form like:

```
<form id="formaa">
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" name="item" class="item"></input>
  <input type="text" name="quant" class="quant"></input>
  <input type="text" name="price" class="price" onkeyup="update();"></input>
  <input type="text" name="sum" id="suma" size="10" disabled="disabled"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" name="item" class="item"></input>
  <input type="text" name="quant" class="quant"></input>
  <input type="text" name="price" class="price" onkeyup="update();"></input>
  <input type="text" name="sum" id="suma" size="10" disabled="disabled"/>
</div>    
<!-- ... many more rows -->
<input type="text" disabled id="total" name="tot"></input>
</form>
```

What I'm trying to do is multiply item quantity and price and get total sum in sum field for each item seperately (not all items total sum).

What I have achiecved is this function, but it seems counting total sum of all items together not seperately and this working with first default field row, when I add new set of fields and fill them with information both, fields (and other later added) sum values become NaN..If I remove all added field sets and leave the first form fows set, number is working again.. What is the problem here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function update() {
  var total = 0;
  $("#formaa div.row").each(function(i,o){
    total += $(o).find(".quant").val() *
        $(o).find(".price").val();
         if(!isNaN(total) && total.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(total);
            }
  });
  $("#formaa div.row #suma").val(total);
}
</script>
```

Comment: consider using fieldset tag in place of div

Comment: Just a side note, this `$("#formaa div.row #suma")` is pointless, an ID can only exist once, so no need to qualify it. This `$("#suma")` would be sufficient.

Comment: @BenEverard `$("#suma")` wouldn't work as each row has an element identified as "suma" (which is wrong). I propose `.find('[name="sum"]')`.

Comment: @dystroy Quite right, I went the same route with the `[name=sum]`, but ingeneral, not point in over qualifying an ID selector.

Comment: That's totally right. It's even detrimental to performances.

Comment: @dystroy so how to change sum? increase number by one on each add?

Comment: You can do that, or you can simply use the name (or any other attribute), like in my example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function update() {
  $("#formaa div.row").each(function(i,o){
     var total = $(o).find(".quant").val() * $(o).find(".price").val();
     if(!isNaN(total) && total.length!=0) {
         sum += parseFloat(total);
     }
     $(o).find('[name="sum"]').val(total);
  });
}
```

A few problems in your code :

- never give the same id to more than one element. That's the reason why I defined the selector on the name
- you weren't resetting the total, so it was the sum of all
- I didn't fix that, but your operation *before* the float parsing is strange (it may depend on the content that I can't see)

Comment: +1, same as me... just a little quicker. jsFiddle for anyone interested >> http://jsfiddle.net/beneverard/YpKJZ/3/

Comment: @Ben Everard Your code is also good it works fine on jsfiddle, but when I add it to my page it only shows total value, sum fields are empty.